# If serialver outputs a serialVersionUID, then all is well?

Tags: java, serialization

If I run `serialver` on a class and it outputs a `serialVersionUID`, does that necessarily and automatically mean that all is well, that the class is truly serializable, that I don't have to check anything else?

Comment: No, it does not. This just generates a "hash" of the class that you can use to uniquely identify the current version. It's almost always better to create your own serial. This says nothing about your logic and whether the class will, in fact, serialise. But this is very easy to test.

Comment: a) How do I generate my own serial (i.e., what factors do I keep in mind)? b) I have quite a few classes that I might have to serialize (for storage in HttpSession), so testing them all might be time prohibitive.

Comment: **TESTING SHOULD NEVER BE TIME PROHIBITIVE**. In fact, in modern development, testing to happen _before_ coding. Now, with that out of the way, the serial is the _version_ of your class. You cannot deserialise classes with different versions. So start with `1` and when you make a change that breaks serialization change it to...`2`.

Comment: What kinds of stuff will break serialization? Adding/removing fields? Changing types? What else? Found something: [Type Changes Affecting Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678) --- is this the sort of stuff you have in mind?

Comment: You have some object `Apple`. You save it. You add a field to `Apple` that is required - say its cultivar. Now you load the old `Apple`. Oops, cultivar is `null`. This depends as much on the mechanics of serialization as your own business logic.

Comment: I only expect to save objects in `HttpSession` for short periods of time. The class definitions will change rarely once code is tested and deployed. Plus the sessions themselves are likely to be short (~30 mins).

Comment: If I save my object Abc in `HttpSession`, retrieve it and `Abc.equals(retrievedAbc)` returns `true`, is that a sufficient test?

Comment: Surely that depends on the `equals` method for `Abc`?? What is sufficient testing depends on how important the data is and how much peace of mind you want to have. If, say, it's baking software and someone suddenly gets a `NotSerializableException` while trying to transfer money that would be unacceptable.

Comment: The difference is between caching in `HttpSession` and retrieving from datastore everytime (which has its own caching), so I don't consider this very critical. If it works, great, if it doesn't, I'll optimize later when bigger issues are out of the way. More interestingly: how can `equals()` returning `true` not mean that the retrieval was correct? Could you add an answer listing all the areas of concern in your mind --- this discussion is getting rather long :-). Do you know a mailing list where this can be explored further? Thanks!

Comment: if the class is not serializable it will return, for instance with class Teacher, Class com.test.Teacher is not Serializable.